# In DropDown Selected_Indexchanged event SelectedValue is always getting reset in First Value

Tags: asp.net, sql, c#-4.0, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have DropdownList which I populate at the time of Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DataTable table = new DataTable();


                string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
                string sqlQuery = "select distinct sname from contacts where sname is not null";


                using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
                {

                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();

                        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
                        {

                            using (OracleDataAdapter ODA = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
                            {

                                ODA.Fill(table);

                            }

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Response.Write("Not Connected" + ex.ToString());
                    }

                }

                //DropDownList1.DataSource = table;
                //DropDownList1.DataValueField = "";

                DropDownList2.DataSource = table;
                DropDownList2.DataValueField = "sname";
                DropDownList2.DataTextField = "sname";



                DropDownList2.DataBind();
            }
}
```

Now I am trying to populate a GridView when the DropDownList's Item changes

```
protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();


            string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
            string val = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;

            string sqlQuery = "SELECT distinct DUTY_DATE FROM DUTY_ROTA,DUTY_TYPES,CONTACTS WHERE DUTY_DATE between SYSDATE and SYSDATE+30  AND DUTY_ROTA.DUTY_TYPE = DUTY_TYPES.DUTY_TYPE AND SNAME IS NOT NULL and contacts.sname = '" + val + "' ORDER BY DUTY_DATE";
            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
            {

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
                    {

                        using (OracleDataAdapter ODA = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {

                            ODA.Fill(table);

                        }

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write("Not Connected" + ex.ToString());
                }

            }

            GridView1.DataSource = table;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
```

I have enabled the AutoPostBack. Now when I am changing a DropDownList item to a different one the Page is loading but always retaining the first value. I tried to debug , I found that

```
string val = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
```

the val variable is always the first value that is returned by the Query. Can anybody please tell me how could I get rid of this. I want to populate the GridView whenever I am selecting any item in the dropdown.

Comment: see if changing to DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value helps?i.e string val = DropDownList2..SelectedItem.Value;

Comment: Its the same. :( , Am I going wrong somewhere verybasic?

Comment: did you try DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text ??

Comment: In your design view make sure you are binding the event properly to DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender event

Comment: @Rafay Yes I tried that too..It is not working. 
Ratna Yes I fired the event from properties at Design View..So it is not the problem I guess

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think that dropdownlist charge again when you select other item. Put a Break Point in Page Load and look if your dropdownlist charge again i don't see other reason. Good Luck

Comment: Thanks - I tried to Debug - DropDown is always populating the first result returned by query, not matter what I select..

Answer (score 0):

Your Drop downlist should look like as following :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Make sure AutoPostBack is Set to TRUE.

One more thing you can try is to select the item when the index is greater than -1.

```
      if(DropDownList2.SelectedIndex != -1) 
    {
        string val = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value;
//    enter code here
     }
```